# Not Receiving realtime updates for location field

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I'm receiving real-time updates for `picture` and `first_name` but not for `location` and `about_me` (in FQL, but named `bio` in the Graph API).

when sending a GET to https://graph.facebook.com/MY_APP_ID/subscriptions

I receive :

```
{
 "data": [
    {
      "object": "user", 
      "callback_url": "http://msocialn.dyndns.org:8000/facebook/subscriptions/callback/", 
      "fields": [
        "about_me", 
        "current_location", 
        "first_name", 
        "last_name", 
        "location", 
        "picture"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

To test this I change the location field (current city) in my Facebook profile (the lake of documentation doesn't really specify what `location` is it about). And it's not working. But It works perfectly when changing my profile picture.

Any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to be sure - have you acquired the permission to read their location from the user account in question?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, /me?fields=location&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN returns the location, and I require `friends_location` and `user_location`permissions for my app.